# Refactoring File

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

I have a problem of refactoring file into a package when I got 'One type argument expected for class Result' after a refactor HomeActivity, HomeView, and HomeAdapter into a package called presentation.
Here is the problem:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI6vr.png
Error 'One type argument expected for class Result'

And here is the code:

HomeActivity:

```
package id.kotlin.belajar.presentation


import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import id.kotlin.belajar.R
import id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeView
import id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeAdapter
import id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeDataSource
import id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeResponse


class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HomeView {
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb_home)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_home)

        val presenter = HomePresenter(this)
        presenter.discoverMovie()
    }

    override fun onShowLoading() {
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    override fun onHideLoading() {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun onResponse(results: List<Result>) {
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@HomeActivity, 
        DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        recyclerView.adapter = HomeAdapter(results)
    }

    override fun onFailure(t:Throwable) {
        Log.e(HomeActivity::class.java.simpleName, "${t.printStackTrace()}")
    }
}
```

HomeAdapter:

```
package id.kotlin.belajar.presentation

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import id.kotlin.belajar.R
import id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeView
import id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeDataSource
import id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeResponse


class HomeAdapter (private val results: List<Result>): RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
        return HomeViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_home,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int){
        holder.bind(results[holder.adapterPosition])
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int{
        return results.count()
    }

    inner class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        fun bind(result: Result){
            with(itemView) {
                val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.original_title)
                name.text = result.title

                val country = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.overview)
                country.text = result.overview
            }
        }

  }
}
```

HomeView:

```
package id.kotlin.belajar.presentation



interface HomeView {
    fun onShowLoading()
    fun onHideLoading()
    fun onResponse(results: List<Result>)
    fun onFailure(t: Throwable)
}
```

I have added some import code path to get access on those program files, but there is no effect to it. I need help, as I'm still beginner of mobile programming

Comment: I think you need to inferred the result T type:  fun onResponse(results: List<Result<String>>) if is an string or another type

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I have added, but when I code inside the HomeAdapter, the problem is related to what you suggest, like result: Result, and then result.Title and result.Overview

Comment: The result that you are using is a custom Result class or is the Kotlin Result class?  If you need in the adapter an object with a title, overview, etc. you could create a data class and avoid the Result name.  Of if this data is named, for example UserUI, then try to send to the ui only the UserUI, or the result with the userUI, List<Result<UserUI>>

Comment: Kotlin Result Class. I use it to get result of data from MovieDb

Comment: So if you try List<Result<MovieDb>> doesn't work? but my advice is to avoid propagate the result data to the ui and the presenter must decided to update the view with the success result or the failure result, for example view?.showList(movies: List<MoviesUI>) and view?.showError()

Comment: I got error Unresolved reference: title & Unresolved reference: overview in coding named HomeAdapter